# How configure Eclipse to compile if and only if ant compiles

Tags: eclipse, ant, configuration, compilation

I need to find a configuration or plugin for Eclipse that makes Eclipse compile if and only if "ant clean all" compiles, and it should work with reasonable performance for a huge project, without having to do thousands of configuration settings in Eclipse. I know other IDE's do this out of the box, but I need to start love Eclipse. Currently I have a project that compiles fine with "ant clean all", but in order to write unit tests I believe I need to convince Eclipse that the project compiles too. I have tried Refresh and Project/Clean without success. I also have tried a little bit with Project/Properties/Builders and adding a ant builder. Although a promising path I got confused: My workspace consist of 80+ different projects and when I usually compile this I go to one particular project folder at the command line and do "ant clean all" and all different subprojects are compiled into a single app. However it would be too bad performance for Eclipse to do "ant clean all" all the time. I would be most grateful for any ideas or links?

Comment: So your project don't compile with eclipse ? (or did I miss something ?)

Comment: No it doesn't. Therefor I cannot run any unit tests from within Eclipse. Still it does compile with ant which is the way we usually compile it, so there is no syntax error really.

Comment: Basically my biggest problem is that I cannot run unit test from within Eclipse and don't know any other fast way to do it. Also all red markers are a bit disturbing.

Answer (score 1):

So your problem is that eclipse don't have the correct classpath for your modules. Eclipse store the classpath of a project in a .classpath file at root of the project.

I'm not an eclipse expert, but I don't think that you will find a plugin able to interpret your build.xml to keep your project dependencies up-to-date with eclipse .classpath files.

I think you have 2 strategies to make it running under eclipse (and using the eclipse compiler advantages) :

1. create an eclipse project for each ant module (i.e. one for each build.xml). If your modules structure is flat, it's probably the best option. BUT you will have to manually configure the dependencies of each module (add the dependent modules as project dependency and export them (tab "export" under project classpath window)
2. create one eclipse project for all your ant modules and "add source folder" one by one to the classpath. It's probably the only solution supported by eclipse if your ant modules aren't in a flat hierarchy. BUT if you start editing code in eclipse: you have good chances to introduce unwanted (and maybe cyclic) dependencies between your modules since eclipse will see everything as a huge single project.

If you have any third party library, you will also have to add them by hand to the classpath.

Comment: Ok, it sounds a bit complicated for such a large project, so maybe it is better to change to IntelliJ that according to rumours handles this automatically. I might be able to do this "invisibly" for other team members.

Comment: I don't think IntelliJ is able to do that automatically. The major advantage of intellij is that it will handle hierarchical modules without problems, but it won't maintain transparently synchronization between custom build.xml and internal project files (*.iml)